# Stored Procedure for Deleting a Record from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am new to stored procedure so i need very much help from you folks,I have three tables Event_Session,Event_Speaker,Session_Speaker. I want to delete Event_Session Record by passing Event_session_id it should also  delete Session_Speaker and Event_Speaker Record simultaneously, Pls help me in this ! Here are the tables

**Event_Session**(Table With fields)

> Event_Session_Id,    Session_name,     Session_Description,    Tags
>
> Navigation Properties: **Session_Speaker**

**Session_Speaker**(Table With fields)

> Event_Session_Id,    Event_Speaker_Id,  created_date
>
> Navigation properties: **Event_Session , Event_Speaker**

**Event_Speaker**(Table With fields)

> Event_Speaker_Id,    Speaker_name,    Created_date
>
> Navigation Properties : **Session_Speaker**

Comment: Sure you need solution for two database brands? Not enough with ['on delete casdade'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment can you brief on the question now , i have described the question with the fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) on `DELETE` action from `Event_Session` table:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER Event_Session_Trigger
AFTER delete ON Event_Session
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM Event_Speaker ss 
    WHERE 
      ss.Event_Speaker_Id = (
           SELECT
              Event_Speaker_Id
           FROM Session_Speaker es
           WHERE
              es.Event_session_id = old.Event_session_id
      )

    DELETE FROM Session_Speaker  es 
    WHERE 
      es.Event_session_id = old.Event_session_id        

END$$
delimiter ;
```

**UPDATE:** As requested the synonym procedure :

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE Event_Session_Procedure(IN Event_Session_Id_Delete INT) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE Event_Speaker_Id_Delete INT;

    SELECT
      Event_Speaker_Id INTO Event_Speaker_Id_Delete
    FROM Session_Speaker es
    WHERE
      es.Event_session_id = Event_Session_Id_Delete

    DELETE FROM Event_Session e
    WHERE 
      e.Event_session_id = Event_Session_Id_Delete

    DELETE FROM Session_Speaker  es 
    WHERE 
      es.Event_session_id = Event_Session_Id_Delete

    DELETE FROM Event_Speaker ss 
    WHERE 
      ss.Event_Speaker_Id = Event_Speaker_Id_Delete

END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

You can execute it by running `CALL Event_Session_Procedure(123);` where 123 is the `Event_Session_Id` that you want to delete

Comment: Thanks Stephan can u give answer for this because i have redited my question

Comment: Your trigger was working well, but one thing is that can i have stored procedure because i am not using cascade delete or trigger in any of my application

Comment: @user2299256 i do not get why you want a stored procedure for this ... since the trigger will be call automatically on each delete vs. ensuring manually that the procedure is called before each delete... think if you issues delete statements from different points on your app... it will be a nightmare to maintain

Comment: The thing is that i am using Asp.Net MVC4 Application With Entity Framework 4.0 and i am deleting the data from UI, so i do not need automatic delete

Comment: DELETE FROM Event_Speaker ss 
    WHERE 
      ss.Event_Speaker_Id = (
           SELECT
              Event_Speaker_Id
           FROM Session_Speaker es
           WHERE
              es.Event_session_id = Event_Session_Id_Delete
      ) resulted an error ->giving The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Session_Speaker_Event_Speaker". The conflict occurred in database "EventMgmt", table "dbo.Session_Speaker", column 'event_speaker_id'.

Comment: i didn't knew you had FK , i've updated the procedure pls check

Answer (score 1):

actually you could do it WITHOUT A TRIGGER and for a beginner i suggest that you do it the easier way

if you can go back to your original script or generate a new query page and try this

firstly be careful of any primary key and foreign key constraints that you have set
but at the very end of the declaration of these simple type in ON DELETE CASCADE

here is an example from one of my database scripts

ALTER TABLE (YOUR TABLE NAME) 
ADD CONSTRAINT (your column_fk FOREIGN KEY (your column) REFERENCES YOUR TABLE(YOUR COLUMN) ON DELETE CASCADE;
GO

so that you can follow what Ive written more easily here is an example directly from my database script

ALTER TABLE TEAMS 
ADD CONSTRAINT DID_fk FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES DEVELOPERS(DID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
GO

What cascade does is simply it goes through the rest of the database and deletes all other references to the deleted item so that you can keep referential integrity

Comment: he doesn't want to use cascade or trigger he wants a procedure

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am not changing my database!